# Vuetify v-autocomplete onchange event inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `<v-autocomplete>` dropdown in a `<v-for>` that I use to select the region for every office that I have in the offices list.
The issue is that I don't understand how to pass the index value inside the `updateRegion` method to associate the current selected value with the correct office region.
Maybe there is another way to do this, but I don't know how.

Here's the semplified code:

```
<template v-for="(office, index) in offices">
    <v-flex xs12 class="mt-3" :key="index">
        <v-card class="white--text">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm4 pr-2>
                        <v-autocomplete
                            :value="office.region.id"
                            :items="regions"
                            :label="Region"
                            @change="updateRegion"
                        ></v-autocomplete>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
    methods: {
        updateRegion(value) {
            // how can I have here the index value?
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

try with below code:

```
<template v-for="(office, index) in offices">
    <v-flex xs12 class="mt-3" :key="index">
        <v-card class="white--text">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm4 pr-2>
                        <v-autocomplete
                            v-model="office.region.id"
                            :items="regions"
                            :label="Region"
                            @change="(event) => updateRegion(event, index)"
                        ></v-autocomplete>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
    updateRegion(value, index) {
       console.log(value);
       console.log(index); 
        // how can I have here the index value?
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's work! Thank you very much, It's is much better to assign `office` instead of `index`, i can access the wanted variable right away.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you want to access the index of the office and the selected value from the v-autocomplete in your updateRegion method. If I'm right this should work like following, by passing the `office.regio.id` and `index` to the method.

I didn't have time to test yet. If it doenst work please let me know.

```
<template v-for="(office, index) in offices">
    <v-flex xs12 class="mt-3" :key="index">
        <v-card class="white--text">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm4 pr-2>
                        <v-autocomplete
                            :value="office.region.id"
                            :items="regions"
                            :label="Region"
                            @change="updateRegion(office.region.id, index)"
                        ></v-autocomplete>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
    methods: {
        updateRegion(value, index) {

            // how can I have here the index value?
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi lwolf, you understood correctly the problem and thanks for the quickly reply. Unfortunately the value is empty, instead the index is correctly passed.